# JShint Ant task

Tags: javascript, ant, eclipse-plugin, jshint

I am currently using the `jshint` plug-in in Eclipse to check the code for compliance with coding standards.

This project is built using Ant and I am trying to find a jshint Ant task (https://github.com/philmander/ant-jshint is no longer being maintained so that it is out of the question) to include jshint checks as part of the build.

My question is, is there any library that provides jshint for Ant, and if not what plug-in for Eclipse could also provide an ant task for checking my Javascript style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only know of the jshint-eclipse plug-in (http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/). It creates error and warning markers within the IDE as you save your Javascript files but does not provide an Ant task.

If you don't mind implementing an Ant task by yourself, you should be able to use its [JSHint](https://github.com/eclipsesource/jshint-eclipse/blob/master/bundles/com.eclipsesource.jshint/src/com/eclipsesource/jshint/JSHint.java) class to accomplish the task.